LazyColumn inside HorizontalPager using the same LazyPagingItems reference but with different filters applied
I have a screen with two tabs to display sweet and salty foods but they are the same paging items source with different filters - for this example it's going to be a boolean, when it's true the request fetches sweets and if it's false the salties.
    // FoodsViewModel.kt
    val filter: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)
    var foods = filter.flatMapLatest {
        foodsRepository.requestFoods(sweets = it).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    // FoodsList.kt
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val foods = viewModel.foods.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = holder.selectedTab) {
        FoodTabs.values().forEachIndexed { index, foodTabs ->
            Tab(
                selected = index == selectedTab,
                onClick = {
                    selectedTabIndex = index
                    viewModel.onTabSelected(index)
                },
                text = {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = foodTabs.title))
                }
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(state = holder.pagerState) { index ->
            when (foods.loadState.refresh) {
                LoadState.Loading -> // Loading component
                is LoadState.Error -> // Error component
                is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                    if (foods.itemCount < 1) {
                        // Empty state component
                    } else {
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        ) {
                            items(
                                  items = foods,
                                  key = { document -> document.id }
                            ) { Text(food) }
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Whenever I change the tab I change the filter value as well.
// FoodsViewModel.kt
fun onTabSelected(index: Int) {
    filter.update { index == 0 }
}

But the problem is: when I change the tab the old list is persisted for a few seconds and then the new data set is shown. Is there a way to fix that problem? I couldn't find anyone with the same issue.
Note: The code shown above is a simplified version of what I have, unfortunately I can't display the whole code just those snippets.
I tried updating the VM's food reference to the pagination by hand but this is not the way it's expected to work since this always resulted in odd behaviours.
EDIT: This only happens when I add those LaunchedEffect lines to make the tabs change on swipe
fun FoodsListEffects(selectedTabIndex: Int, pagerState: PagerState, onTabSelected: (Int) -> Unit) {
LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectedTabIndex) { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(selectedTabIndex) }
LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState.currentPage, pagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
    if (!pagerState.isScrollInProgress) onTabSelected(pagerState.currentPage)
}

}
If I comment that code the tab change works without persisting the old data set.

What if you try to only comment the if statement in the FoodsListEffects?

I did and it worked but I'd like to change the tab with a swipe.
